# Convert date time vector

Tags: r

I would expected that df3 and df4 has the same output but it isnt, what is the difference?

```
tim.seq<-seq(as.POSIXlt("2013-07-01 00:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT"),
             as.POSIXlt("2013-07-16 12:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT"),by="12 hours")
df<-data.frame(times=factor(tim.seq))

df2<-df
df2[,"times"]<-as.POSIXlt(as.character(df2[,"times"]),origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")

df3<-df
df3$times<-as.POSIXlt(as.character(df3[,"times"]),origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")
for(i in df3$times) print(i)

t<-as.POSIXlt(as.character(df[,"times"],origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT"))
df4<-data.frame(times=t)
for(i in df4$times) print(i)
```

Comment: I get an error `character string is not in a standard unambiguous format` in your line `df2[,"times"] = ...`

Comment: that is correct I would show that df2 is not working, df3 is not the result I am looking for but df4 is what I expected. And I cant explain where are the differnces.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the following:

```
typeof(df3$times) # type = "list"

typeof(df4$times) # type = "double"

typeof(unlist(df3$times)) # now it has the same type (double)
```

because the two are not of the same type the output differs, because R prints them in a different way.

More interesting is the question why the difference occur. I think (please correct me in case I´m wrong) the difference is that in the first case it overrides `df3$times` with a list. In the second case, you construct the df directly, therefore it you get a `double` type after indexing and in the first case a `list` after indexing.

Maybe someone else has a better explanation...

hth